# File not found exception in background downloader

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

I am trying to resume background downloads once the app become active but it always gives file not found exception at .GetCurrentDownloadsAsync()

```
        IReadOnlyList<DownloadOperation> downloads = null;
        try
        {
            downloads = await BackgroundDownloader.GetCurrentDownloadsAsync();
            if (downloads.Count <= 0)
                return;

            foreach (DownloadOperation op in downloads)
            {

                op.Resume();

            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
```

Comment: DownloadOperation.Resume() method is for resuming paused downloads. Your download operation itself is a background download. So it doesn't matter if your app is in the foreground or not.

Comment: See this page for details: Transferring data in the background (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh452979.aspx)

Comment: Can you get Fiddler traces between your computer and the website to see what's going on??

Comment: Please show the complete exception, rather than just the message.

Answer (score 1):

I remember reading about a similar bug a while ago. It was fixed by uninstalling the app and then re-running the app from visual studio.

Comment: Where are you calling the above code from? Are you sure the app is fully loaded when it is called?

Comment: calling from MainPage_Loaded in mainpage

Comment: Seems like you are doing it right. I would try creating a new app and running the code from there to see if it only happens for this app. Also posting the entire exception might help as well.

Comment: I'm getting the same issue.  My exception message is `The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)`

Comment: It's a weird bug, it seems that it happens when you stop debugging abruptly and then run app again. Cleaning and rebuilding the solution helped me, too.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to fix this without re-installing the app and it may be possible to do this in-code. It does feel like a hack however, but I have not seen any official acknowledgement about this bug.

In your app's local storage folder (the one that contains the 'LocalState' folder) delete everything in AC/BackgroundTransferApi